# Java Jackson Deserialization of Nested Objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, aws-lambda

Working with AWS Lambdas, and when one fails due to an exception, AWS serializes that exception as JSON and sends it back to whatever invoked that Lambda.  Here's what that might look like:

```
{  
     "errorMessage":"USER_SERVICE_FAILURE",
     "errorType":"com.company.project.lambda.core.exceptions.LambdaFailureException",
     "stackTrace":[  
        "com.company.project.lambda.worker.MainWorkerLambda.handleRequest(AccountWorker.java:127)",
        "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
        "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
        "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
        "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
     ],
     "cause":{
        "errorMessage":"some other exception error message",
        "errorType":"com.company.project.lambda.core.exceptions.SomeOtherException",
        "stackTrace":[  
           "insert other stack trace strings here...",
           "...",
           "..."
        ],
        "cause":{
           "errorMessage": "...",
           ...continue in to perpetuity...
        }
     }
}
```

The `errorMessage`, `errorType`, and `stackTrace` fields are easy enough to deserialize - they will *always* be a single `String`, a single `String`, and a `List<String>` respectively.

Where I'm stuck is the `cause` field.  This could be an empty object if there is no cause, or one nested exception, or two, or a hundred...

How do I deserialize this?  Here's my POJO so far.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ExceptionRep {
    String errorMessage;

    String errorType;

    List<String> stackTrace;

    // how do I do the cause field?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your class as a node structure that has an attribute of its same type:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ExceptionRep {
    String errorMessage;
    String errorType;
    List<String> stackTrace;
    private ExceptionRep cause;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply reuse your `ExceptionRep` class for the reference type, and annotate the object as optional (so if there is no cause in the JSON, it won't fail de-serialization).

Something like:

```
@JsonProperty(required=false)
ExceptionRep child;
```

This way if there are nested causes, they are recursively de-serialized. 
If there are none, the property is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap if you don't want to have to define all the properties in a custom class.